# How to add event listener to div without tabindex=0?

Tags: javascript, html

I have something like this control:

[image]

I need to track focus on any element inside this control. If I focus input or If I focus (click) calendar icon, I want to know that focus performed.

My idea is to add click listener on wrapper of input + calendar trigger. It is some div.

Out of the box I can't add focus listener to the div. To achieve this I need to add `tabindex=0` to this div. This method will work, but it has one minus.

For example, I have form with many controls. Example code is below:

```
<div class="container">
  <input onfocus="onFocus()" />
  <div tabindex="0" onfocus="onFocus()">some div</div>
  <div tabindex="0" onfocus="onFocus(event.target)">
    <input onfocus="onFocus()" />
  </div>
  <input onfocus="onFocus()" />
</div>
```

When I focus first input and start looping through `TAB` key I want this behavior: focus calendar icon, focus next input, focus next calendar icon etc. But with `tabindex=0` I break this behaviour. You can check it in [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gqQNwP). You can see this broken behaviour after `some div` block.

Well, I have another option to add listener specifically for input and calendar icon (or any other icon). The problem is I have dynamic amount of icons on each field. And I have to add focus listener for each. Much simpler for me (and another developers) is the way when I have only one focus listener on the top (as I think).

Is it somehow possible to add ability to add focus listener to the `div` without breaking focus loop (like I shown on the codepen example).

Comment: Won't it work if you give it an appropriate tabindex (i.e., not 0, but 2 and 3)?

Comment: Hm. But it will be still focusable by tab, won't it? I don't want it.

Comment: Use `div.addEventListener('focusin', handler)`. `focus` and `blur` don't bubble, `focusin` and `focusout` do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `element.addEventListener('focusin', handler)`. `focus` and `blur` don't bubble, `focusin` and `focusout` do.

```js
document.querySelector('.container')
  .addEventListener('focusin', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target)
  })
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input name="a" />
  <div contenteditable="true">some div</div>
  <div>
    <input name="b" />
  </div>
  <input name="c"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, focusin/focusout bubles and with input field this works. In my case I have not only input in my wrapper. Also, I have divs. I want to track focus/blur on them too. focusin/focusout event is not triggered for them when I click them. Ok, I realized that focus/blur way is not correct for me. I changed approach a bit and now it works. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: ```event.relatedTarget``` was of big help to me whilst solving a similar use case.
it contains the next focused element in case of focusout